# How do I create a ViewModel for each page in a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle

I have a `ViewPager`, where I show multiple instances of `PetFragment`. To create a new instance of a `PetFragment`, I call `PetFragment.newInstance(petId)`.

I want a separate `ViewModel` instance for each `petId`. But [`ViewModelProvider.Factory#create()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.Factory.html#create(java.lang.Class<T>)) only takes a `Class<T>` as a parameter. How do I achieve this?

Comment: is your problem solved ? . I too have same problem . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54862222/viewpager-with-viewmodel-and-live-data-all-6-tabs-data-is-replaced-by-last-tab

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `ViewModelProvider.get(@NonNull String key, @NonNull Class<T> modelClass)`, you should be able to have multiple ViewModels for a specific class stored by key.

`ViewModelProvider.get(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass)` just calls that first method with a default key.

The get call interacts with `ViewModelStore` which is a wrapper around a `HashMap<String, ViewModel>`, which should allow you to store various `ViewModel`s for the same type of Fragment, as long as each has a key that's unique to identifying what it should display.

Comment: nice. this helped me.

Comment: tried same didn't worked for me .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54862222/viewpager-with-viewmodel-and-live-data-all-6-tabs-data-is-replaced-by-last-tab